# Building node.js modules in windows

Tags: node.js

I've got two questions:

1) Is it possible to build modules for node.js in windows?

2) Can compiled libraries (*.node) be incompatible between *nix and windows versions of node?

Comment: Do you mean extension of node.js in C/C++ or do you mean javascript module?

Comment: c/cc++ that npm tries to make while install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer for anyone coming across this old question:

Yes this is now possible with node-gyp which replaces node-waf.

https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp

Answer (score 1):

1) As far as I've seen when installing things for my application in Windows with NPM, some modules are indeed compiled (if I'm not mistaken, the MongoDB module is one of them).

2) I'm not an expert in C or C++, but the advice is to compile modules each time you "move" your app to a different OS. Take for example the Node hosting services no.de and nodejitsu, they ask you for the package.json file and install dependencies themselves.

Comment: Compiled while installing with NPM? Using what tool? I've looked inside of *.node (i've got both versions for windows and mac for one of the libraries) file, and they are really different =) Actually its just an executable for OS (like *.exe for windows), I believe so you can't use one for *nix and windows. Try to get it compiled now with python and MS VS (like in installation instruction s of node it self https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installation)

Comment: I was talking about the Node.js modules, not *.node files. For example when you want to install Express and do 'npm install express'.

Comment: But what do you mean by "compiled"?

Comment: Well if the modules has C bindings you have to build it somehow, check more here: http://howtonode.org/how-to-module

Comment: Yes but AFAIK npm has no way to build c/c++ addons in windows https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/2136