# node-serialport O/S requirements

Tags: node.js, node-serialport

I need to be able to read the serial port from within my JS code. I recently stumbled across this component
https://github.com/voodootikigod/node-serialport

What are the requirements for the client computer O/S?

To install it, all it says to do is

```
 npm install serialport
```

What is that? Where should this command be run? More details would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The module you've pointed out is for [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) an event-driven Javascript application server.  The emphasis here is that node.js is server-side, not something that runs in a browser.

The command you've pointed out invokes [npm](http://npmjs.org/), a package manager for node.js.  You would need to execute that command on the server where the code expects to run.

While only the author of the code will be able to give you an authoritative answer, a quick review of both the [Javascript](https://github.com/voodootikigod/node-serialport/blob/master/serialport.js) and the [C++ code](https://github.com/voodootikigod/node-serialport/blob/master/serialport_native/serialport_native.cc) doesn't seem to reveal anything that's platform specific.

Well, as long as you can compile that C++ code.  That [looks to be a problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8462846/building-node-js-modules-in-windows) if your server is on Windows.

The library seems to want to treat the serial port as a regular file.  While this should be an obvious way to do it if you're on a Unixish operating system (Linux, BSD, Solaris, OS X, etc -- though I don't think Macs have had serial ports in a few decades), it's not immediately clear or obvious if you can just ask Windows to open `COM1` and have it work correctly.

So, chances are that you'll have a much larger chance of success if you're hosting this on a Unix than on Windows.

Comment: thanks Charles. I wish the component author pitches in his opinion. Our servers are Windows unfortunately...does this mean then that node.js only works on Unix servers?

Comment: I just found this http://www.guardian.co.uk/technology/blog/2011/nov/09/programming-microsoft

Comment: looks like Microsoft is embracing node.js

Comment: Oh, node.js will work fine on Windows servers, it's just that this component includes a binary extension that needs to be compiled, and the framework for *that* doesn't seem to be present yet.

Comment: As of today, node-serialport compiles and runs reliably on Windows.  (You do need [Python and VC++](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp#installation) installed for the build process to run when installing with npm.)

Comment: And now it doesn't! See the Issues log on GitHub. In particular, it seems that it is dependent on the costly full version of MS Visual Studio on 64-bit OS's (even when trying to use Node et al as 32bit).